# cant get junit running with Karma

Tags: junit, karma-runner

I have installed the npm package karma-junit-reporter at version 2.0.1.

my karma.conf.js file is :

```
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false, // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
      captureConsole: true
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './coverage/ClientApp'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
    // the default configuration
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'test', // results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName.xml
      outputFile: 'junit.xml', // if included, results will be saved as $outputDir/$browserName/$outputFile
      //suite: '', // suite will become the package name attribute in xml testsuite element
      //useBrowserName: false, // add browser name to report and classes names
      //nameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the name attribute in xml testcase element
      //classNameFormatter: undefined, // function (browser, result) to customize the classname attribute in xml testcase element
      //properties: {}, // key value pair of properties to add to the <properties> section of the report
      //xmlVersion: null // use '1' if reporting to be per SonarQube 6.2 XML format
    }
  });
};
```

When I run:

> ng test --reporters junit

I receive the following error:

can not load reporter "junit", it is not registered! Perhaps you are missing some plugin?
[karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok. I found the answer by chance. Really weird, but this worked. I needed to explicitly mention the config file :

```
ng test --karma-config=karma.conf.js --reporters junit
```

it now works even though I was running the ng test command from the same directory as my karma.conf.js file